# Auto skip heading rows in csv File php

Tags: php

I am working with an problem that csv file may contain heading so, how can we skip that heading or extra information and skip to main data(csv data)

CSV Data may like :

```
   **Heading 1**
This is some extra text before Data
date: xx-xx-xxxx
country data: A,B,C

     *Then here starts the Data(comma separated values)*  

Col1,col2,col3, 
dataCol1,datacol2,datacol3 ....
```

so how can we skip to main data and process that data

any help will be appreciated.. as i tried but cant fix it 
Thanks

Comment: You need a way to determine where the _data_ starts.

Comment: Do you always know what line the data will start on, or is this something that the program will have to determine at runtime?

Comment: no, it  depend on, who create and uploads the data, no fixed num of line can predict...

Comment: No problem. Let's call the section you want to exclude the "metadata" - will there always be at least one blank line between the metadata and the data? I assume that the literal sentence `*Then here starts the Data(comma separated values)*` won't be part of the file?

Comment: yeah, *Then here starts the Data(comma separated values)*  this line is not included and yes there is an empty row .. so should i find  empty row??

Answer (score 0):

You need to find some kind of delimiter or pattern you can use to indicate where the data starts. For example:

- Do you know if the header will always be a certain number of lines?
- Will it always have a blank line after it like in your example?
- etc.

Once you know that, you can test to see if the file contains that pattern/delimiter, and then skip to the csv part.

> thanks, but it is uncertain, heading section may be or not present... – Abzkn

That's the trick - you need to find out what conditions would be there if it was present. Then test for those conditions. For example, if you know the header is always 4 lines and the next one is a blank line, you could do something like this:

```
<?php
$f = file_get_contents($filename); //get everything in the file being processed

$file_lines = explode("\n", $f); //break up each line into an array we can process

$start_line = 0; //assume the header is not present and we'll start processing from line 1

if($file_lines[4] == ''){
    //header is present, so start processing from line 5
    $start_line = 5;
}

for($l = $start_line;$l < count($file_lines;$l++){
    //process each line
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means a perfect solution, because there are some unknowns in your question - therefore I have to make an of assumption: there will be more rows of csv column data than metadata/header lines. In order to assist in this heuristic, we will also exclude all "empty" lines.

If we can make this assumption then we can do something like the following:

```
<?php

// define filepath... optionally validate
// with `is_file()` and `is_writable()`
$file = __DIR__ . '/data.csv';

// create an SplFileObject
$csv = new SplFileObject($file);

// set some flags to read file transparently
// as a csv. drop `SKIP_EMPTY` will ignore all
// blank lines as specified above
$csv->setFlags(
    SplFileObject::DROP_NEW_LINE |
    SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD    |
    SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY    | 
    SplFileObject::READ_CSV
);

// init an empty array to store rows
$rows  = [];

// an `SplFileObject` allows iteration
// over its contents with `foreach`.
foreach ($csv as $row) {
    // stash each row into a sub-array
    // indexed by its length (number of columns)
    $rows[count($row)][] = $row;
}

// `max()` will return the biggest sub-array
// which will be the column data according 
// to our assumptions stated above
$csvData = max($rows);

var_dump($csvData);
```

If the contents of `$file` contained:

```
       **Heading 1**
This is some extra text before Data
date: xx-xx-xxxx
country data: A,B,C

     *Then here starts the Data(comma separated values)*

Col1,col2,col3
dataCol1,datacol2,datacol3
dataCol1,datacol2,datacol3
dataCol1,datacol2,datacol3
```

We should expect the following result:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>     country data: A
            [1] => B
            [2] => C
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>     Col1
            [1] => col2
            [2] => col3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] =>     dataCol1
            [1] => datacol2
            [2] => datacol3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] =>     dataCol1
            [1] => datacol2
            [2] => datacol3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] =>     dataCol1
            [1] => datacol2
            [2] => datacol3
        )

)
```

Which looks pretty good - except... the line `country data: A,B,C` has been parsed as a valid row, because it also includes two commas. That's the problem with trying to program heuristically. I don't know if this will be a problem in your specific use case. If so, some refinement of the above approach might be required.

References:

- [`SplFileObject()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php)
- [`SplFileObject::setFlags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.setflags.php)
- [`max()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @Abzkn No problem :) Let me know if you have any further questions etc. And don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if you find it solves your question ;)